# Getting a linker error when trying to build Android project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I get this linker error every time I attempt to build my Android project, with the linker set to SDK only.

```
Error       Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Utilities.AttributeProvider::GetTypeDescriptor(System.Type)' in assembly: 'EntityFramework.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider::.ctor(System.Type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()   TraceIt.Android
```

**Build settings:**
[image: settings]
[image: settings2]
[image: settings3]
[image: settings4]
[image: settings5]
[image: settings6]
[image: settings7]
[image: settings8]

Comment: How about "linking: none"?

Comment: @Shaw that isn’t encouraged, since my startup time is larger, and the app size is greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure to only target Arm64, since this is the default supported architecture now on Google Play.

Second, make sure to switch to a dx compiler instead of d8. I know Google recommends to switch to a d8/r8 compiler implementation but, from experience it's still not stable, and has stripped allot of Apis that previous projects I was involved in dependended on. (Square SDK for example).

Third, it looks like your android client is referencing source code that is not compatable with the Android Runtime. Try to hide the implementation by using **SOLID** principle of Interface Segregation (where you hide the implementation of the classes through interfaces and dependency injection, and let another library to manage the implementation for you. If you can prevent the client from referencing the implementation that's causing your issue directly, by abstracting it, then the linker should work for you.

Fourth, always make sure to link source code, in order to minimise the size of your apk. Also it speeds up development, and make sure to enable Shared MonoRuntime. It's supported on Android 6 and above.

Comment: I’ll try the first couple things you’ve suggested, but I have concerns about the others. On your third point, I haven’t directly referenced anything to do with the EntityFramework method that the linker has a problem with. The only platform specific code I have for Android is for custom renderers to do with gradients and such. Your fourth point, do you meant set the linker to ‘All’? I’ve heard that is risky and can cause problems down the track

Comment: After checking, the Shared Runtime is designated for debugging purposes (fast re-deployment) not release. Further, by unchecking armeabi-v7a, would I not be blocking 32-bit Android devices from using my app?

Comment: Okay, so it seems linker set to 'SDK & User Assemblies' builds with no issue, while SDK only fails on both dx and d8.

Comment: You were right on your third point, I had installed the EntityFramework package in all projects some point in the past, and the Android project didn't like that at all. I never actually used it, forgot about it, and then thought it was a Xamarin dependency up until this point.